# mysqli bind_result/fetch problem

Tags: php, mysqli

I am learning how to use prepared statements with php 5 mysqli objects and I am having trouble getting the basic result binding to work. I am following the example code from php.net but something isn't working, the bound results are always NULL. Here is what I have

/* prepare statement */

```
if ($stmt = $DB->mysqli->prepare("SELECT `alias`,`nameFirst`,`nameLast`,`email`,`access_level` FROM `users` WHERE `alias` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') LIMIT 20;")) {

                   $stmt->bind_param('s',$alias);

                    $stmt->execute();

                    /* bind variables to prepared statement */
                    $stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2);

                    /* fetch values */
                    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                    echo "COL 1=".$col1." | COL2=".$col2."<br />";
                    }

                    /* close statement */
                    $stmt->close();
                } else echo "NO DICE";
```

Comment: I had the same problem as the OP, but the cause for me was that I had a **comma** missing in my `SELECT a, b, c, d, e f, g` statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ooops, I missed the note right on the php docs:

> Note that all columns must be bound after `mysqli_stmt_execute()` 
>   and prior to calling `mysqli_stmt_fetch()`.

Found the answer here:

[Prepared Statement not returning anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019959/prepared-statement-not-returning-anything)

Answer (score -3):

Or, you can all fields in an array like `$cols[]`.  While printing you can use echo `$cols[0].$cols[1]` and so on.